Corrección código en C
Estoy reescribiendo los ejercicios de pseudocódigo en C y me he encontrado atascado con esto:
Debo hacer un ejercicio que:
Dada una frase por el usuario, realice un algoritmo que me diga cuantas palabras terminan con la misma letra que la primera palabra.
En pseudocódigo tengo algo como esto:
algoritmo
   var
       c, cont, cant, cult
   fvar
   escribir("Introduce una frase");
   leer(c);
   cont = 0;
   cant = c;
   mientras (c!='.') hacer;
       leer(c);
       mientras (c != ' ') y (c != '.') hacer;
           cult = c;
           leer(c);
       fmientras
       si (cant == cult) entonces;
           cont = cont + 1;
       fsi
       si (c != '.') entonces;
           leer(c);
       fsi
   fmientras
   escribir("Acaban con la misma letra ", cont, " palabras");
falgoritmo

A la hora de escribir ese programa en C tengo esta implementación:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   char c, cant, cult;
   int cont = 0;

   printf("Introduce una frase: \n");
   scanf("%c", &c);
   cant = c;

   while (c != '.') {
       while (c != ' ' && c != '.') {
           cult = c;
           scanf("%c", &c);
       }
       if (cant == cult) {
           cont++;
       }
       if (c != '.') {
           scanf("%c", &c);
       }
   }
   printf("Acaban con la misma letra que la primera palabra: %d palabras.\n", cont);

   return 0;
}

El problema que surge de este código es que a pesar de introducir una frase con palabras que terminan con igual letra que la primera palabra, siempre está en 0.
¿Qué está sucediendo? ¿Es algún error de mi pseudocódigo?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char c, cant = ' ';
int cont = 0;

printf("Introduce una frase \n");
   while ((c = getchar()) != '.') {
if (cant == 's' && (c == '.' || c == ' ')) {
cont++;
}
cant = c;
   }

printf("Acaban con s %d palabras.\n", cont);

return 0;
}

Tengo este código de un ejercicio anterior que cuenta las palabras que acaban en s, y que pienso que puede ser clave para resolver este problema. Muchas gracias por leerme :)

Puedes dar un ejemplo de la entrada? El resultado puede variar de acuerdo al comportamiento de leer y scanf.

He probado con esta frase al azar:
Conoces caminos relativos a este?.
El resultado de ejecutar con esta frase es 0 palabras que acaban igual que la primera palabra.

Te falta el paso más importante. Identificar la última letra de la primera palabra.
int main() {
   printf("Introduce una frase: \n");

   int cont = 0;
   char letra = 0, ultimaLetra = 0;
   char debeTerminar = 0;

   while (true) {
      scanf("%c", &letra);
      if (letra == '.') break;

      if (letra == ' ' && ultimaLetra != ' ') {
         if (debeTerminar == 0)
            debeTerminar = ultimaLetra;
         else if (ultimaLetra == debeTerminar)
            cont++;
      }
      ultimaLetra = letra;
   }
   printf("Acaban con la misma letra que la primera palabra: %d palabras.\n", cont);

   return 0;
}

Para que funcione correctamente con cualquier frase, deberías cambiar la condición, por ejemplo verificar si es una letra con isalpha.
if(!isalpha(letra) && isalpha(ultimaLetra))


El problema en tu código está creo yo en cómo estás manejando la captura de la primera y la última letra de las palabras. Aunque la lógica en pseudocódigo está bien planteada, en la implementación en C hay detalles que hacen que el programa no funcione como quieres. El primer problema es que el carácter inicial cant no se está asignando correctamente. Necesitamos que cant almacene la última letra de la primera palabra completa, no solo un carácter al azar. Por otro lado, el carácter final de cada palabra cult se debe capturar correctamente antes de evaluar si coincide con cant.
Codigo:
´
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <ctype.h>
int main() {
    char c, cant = '\0', cult = '\0'; // `cant` es la última letra de la primera palabra
    int cont = 0, palabra_iniciada = 0;
    printf("Introduce una frase (termina con '.'): \n");
    while ((c = getchar()) != '.') {
        if (!palabra_iniciada && !isspace(c)) {
            palabra_iniciada = 1; 
            if (cant == '\0') {
                cant = c; 
            }
        }
        if (palabra_iniciada && !isspace(c)) {
            cult = c;
        }
        if (palabra_iniciada && isspace(c)) {
            palabra_iniciada = 0; 
            if (cult == cant) {
                cont++; 
            }
        }
    }
    if (palabra_iniciada && cult == cant) {
        cont++;
    }
    printf("Acaban con la misma letra que la primera palabra: %d palabras.\n", cont);
    return 0;
}

´
